# What's the effect of monitor in keras?

Tags: keras

In Keras, we use ModelCheckpoint to save our trained models. In a document of Keras, it explains that "monitor: quantity to monitor.", but I still can't understand it. What's the effect of monitor in our machine learning process?

```py
keras.callbacks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://keras.io/callbacks/

From the keras documentation, I'm explaining the parameters of the ModelCheckpoint. It's used to save your best model while training, the reason is maybe after training for few epochs the model may start to diverge or show poor performance/ may get overfitted. Many epochs do not always mean best performance, so it's better to keep saving the weights while training.

**save_best_only: if save_best_only=True, the latest best model according to the quantity monitored will not be overwritten.** Here, it clearly says, the model will be saved based on the value of the quantity to be monitored.

**mode: one of {auto, min, max}. If save_best_only=True, the decision to overwrite the current save file is made based on either the maximization or the minimization of the monitored quantity. For val_acc, this should be max, for val_loss this should be min, etc. In auto mode, the direction is automatically inferred from the name of the monitored quantity.** 
The mode will be determined based on your monitoring metric, if it's a loss then the mode must be min, if it's something like accuracy, f1 score etc. then the mode must be max. (You want to save the weights which shows least loss, and best accuracy so far)

**verbose: verbosity mode, 0 or 1.** verbose determines how much information you want to get printed about your metrics (0 means nothing will be printed, 1 means some information will be printed)

Other parameters should be very easy to understand.